# extract data from list with same key to dictionary?

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I had asked a similar question here and it helped. But after some QA testing, i noticed i bug in my logic (new to python). Im using fabric to connect to remote linux server to run commands and collect the data. Unfortunately, the data can have same key's with different values. I would like to create a dictionary from this data and for those with the same key name, put all the values into that one key. Also, how can i have fabric hide output on the console.

Various test playing around with syntax, defaultdict, and some other things i found googling which i couldn't get to work

## command executed on remote server

```
bpimage_cmd = ssh_connect.run(rf"sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpimagelist -L -backupid {last_backup_image} -media | egrep -e 'Policy:' -e 'ID:' -e 'Client:'")
```

## Output of bpimage_cmd.stdout.split('\n')

```
['Client:            hostname',
 'Backup ID:         hostname_1555217510',
 'Policy:            POLICY-ONE',
 'Proxy Client:      (none specified)',
 'Job ID:            4630072',
 'Data_Classification_ID: (none specified)',
 'Storage Lifecycle Policy:    SLP-DATA-Infinite',
 'Origin Master GUID:    (none specified)',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaax',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               @aaaar',
 ' ID:               L02460',
 ' ID:               L02512',
 '']
```

## Command i'm using to turn to a dict,

```
backup_client_info = dict(re.split(r":\s*",s.strip(),1) for s in bpimage_cmd.stdout.split('\n') if s.strip())

backup_client_info
{'Client': 'hostname',
 'Backup ID': 'hostname_1555217510',
 'Policy': 'POLICY-ONE',
 'Proxy Client': '(none specified)',
 'Job ID': '4630072',
 'Data_Classification_ID': '(none specified)',
 'Storage Lifecycle Policy': 'SLP-DATA-Infinite',
 'Origin Master GUID': '(none specified)',
 'ID': 'L02512'}
```

It makes sense to me why it keeps only one  "ID" because it needs to be unique in a dict.

I would like to have all the ID values in one key where the value isn't @aaa*, like 'ID': 'L02512','L02460' in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. It is verbose so you can see the different steps I've taken.

```
backup_client_info = {}

# assume you are storing the split data into bpimage_cmd_split
bpimage_cmd_split = bpimage_cmd.stdout.split('\n')

for item in bpimage_cmd_split:

    # don't do anything if content is not valuable
    if len(item.strip()) == 0:
        continue

    # split the data and clean both key and value
    data_split = [s.strip() for s in item.split(':')]

    if data_split[0] == 'ID':
        if not '@aaa' in data_split[1]:

            # If ID is not in dict yet, add it as a list
            # If ID is already there, append to the list
            if data_split[0] not in backup_client_info:
                backup_client_info[data_split[0]] = [data_split[1]]
            else:
                backup_client_info[data_split[0]].append(data_split[1])    
    else:
         backup_client_info[data_split[0]] = data_split[1]    

print(backup_client_info)
```

**Output**

```
{
   'Client':'hostname',
   'Backup ID':'hostname_1555217510',
   'Policy':'POLICY-ONE',
   'Proxy Client':'(none specified)',
   'Job ID':'4630072',
   'Data_Classification_ID':'(none specified)',
   'Storage Lifecycle Policy':'SLP-DATA-Infinite',
   'Origin Master GUID':'(none specified)',
   'ID':[
      'L02460',
      'L02512'
   ]
}
```

Whenever you have to use ID, you can just do a join `', '.join(ID)` and you will get a comma separated string.

Comment: @neoluu I didn't understand the question. Can you ask again and provide an example of what you need?

Comment: Hi zedfoxus, awesome and thanks for the verbose. Instead of print(backup_client_info). I will use an "if key in backup_client_info: backup_tape_id = backup_client_info.get("ID"). I get this output, 
"['L02460', 'L02512']" .  i want to strip characters and have came to this command: backup_tape_id.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("\'",'').strip(",")
output: 'L02460, L02512'.  Just wondering, there must be a more proper way?

Comment: Yeah, you can do this `if ID in backup_client_info: backup_tape_id = ', '.join(backup_client_info["ID"])`. Try that.